# 'android:clickable="false"' did not work in view

Tags: android, xml

Hai i am trying to set my view to be *`clickable='false'`* in the xml. The view will only be displayed when i click my FAB plus for the first time and close when i click it again. I want everything behind the view which is tabs and actionbar cannot be click/swipe or anything when the view is visible. So my question is why i can still click and swipe the tabs although i already set the view's clickable as false? Is there anything wrong with what i do? How can i achieve this? Please advice me on this. Thank you!

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab1" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab2" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadowView"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#BFFFFFFF"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

Method to call when fab plus is click:

```
public void fabVisibility(){
        if (isOpen){
            fabPlus.startAnimation(fabRotateAntiClockwise);
            shadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isOpen = false;
        }else {
            fabPlus.startAnimation(fabRotateClockwise);
            fabPlus.setEnabled(true);
            shadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isOpen = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: try `android:selectable=false`

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Is there anything else that i miss out or anything?

Comment: Have you tried setting your shadow `clickable="true"`? It will consume the clicks and prevent interaction with tabs behind it.

Comment: @Pawel Hey it works! Thank you! Thank you! I never think of that way. Thank you so much!